# Python type annotation for nested lists

Tags: python, annotations, typing

I'd like to annotate my return type which happens to be a list containing lists of integers. Is this annotation: `List[List[int]]` okay? Here's exact example of my return type:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Can you explain better your desired output?

Comment: I'm unsure if mypy reads nested annotations in this form `List[List[int]]`, where `List` is from the `typing` module.  There may be another way.

Comment: So I have n filenames like lets take for example 10. Each filename has three attributes. So I parse them in a nested listed which is like this

    list[ list[ints], list[ints], list[ints]...... ]
so basically nested list.  i wanted to annotate it like this
    list[list[int]] 
I am not sure if mypy can read it or possible its sufficient to write like this 
    list[list]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `List[List[int]]` is the correct type.

As a side note, whenever you're unsure of the type, you can define that variable and use the Mypy `reveal_type` method to have it guess the correct type. For example:

```sh
> cat foo.py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
reveal_type(a)

> mypy foo.py
1.py:2: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.list*[builtins.int]]'
```

which tells you that the type of `a` is `List[List[int]]`. Note that `reveal_type` is not a valid function; it's rather a special syntax built into Mypy. If you try to run `foo.py` in Python, it'll throw a `NameError`.

For more information, consider reading the [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#when-you-re-puzzled-or-when-things-are-complicated).